# Copy and paste Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro I use for pasting in excel it works fine except when copy and pasting from one cell to another. In other words it works fine with say text from a webpage but not from one cell to another. The error message says `Run time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed.` Here is the code:

```
Sub MousePaste()
'
' MousePaste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, when copying one cell to another, that can't be accomplished with the hotkey Ctrl+V?  NB: You can eliminate `ActiveCell.Select` -- it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

There are two implementations of a PasteSpecial method.

[Worksheet.PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835858(v=office.15).aspx) which pastes from the clipboard and

[Range.PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx) which pastes from/to a range.

You probably need the latter, examples in the above links.

Comment: Is there a way to use the Range.PasteSpecial dynamically? I want it to paste into whatever cell I have selected. Thanks, Garrett.

Comment: something like this  ActiveCell.Copy then separate line            
 .Range("D1:D5").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd

Comment: That will paste into D1:D5 every time I want it to paste into whatever cell I happen to have selected.

Comment: AH I thought you wanted the ActiveCell to be copied, not receive the copied value.  So what is it you want to copy?  And Yes, in my example you would have to specify the range to copy into.

Comment: I have two separate macro's one for copy and one for paste.These are set up as shortcuts with my mouse wheel, so I move it to the left to copy and to the right to paste. So my paste macro just needs to paste whatever happens to be on the clipboard at the time. It also needs to paste special so I am only pasting the values and I don't have to fix the formatting later. Thanks, Garrett.

Comment: AH again - then you do need the Worksheet.PasteSpecial method. Your paste macro should just read _ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial_ which assumes your cursor is in your destination cell and there is something on the clipboard.

Comment: I deleted the activecell.select but I still get the same error.